# How to reference properties and values in JSON-LD?

Tags: json, json-ld, structured-data

I found a [few examples of JSON-LD code](https://github.com/luminarious/jsonld-examples/blob/master/examples), such as [this blog article](https://github.com/luminarious/jsonld-examples/blob/master/examples/BlogPosting.json):

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "headline": "14 Ways Json Can Improve Your SEO",
  "alternativeHeadline": "and the women who love them",
  "image": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
  "award": "Best article ever written",
  "editor": "John Doe",
  "genre": "search engine optimization",
  "keywords": "seo sales b2b",
  "wordcount": "1120",
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Elsevier",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "http://example.com/logo.jpg"
    }
  },
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "datePublished": "2015-09-20",
  "dateCreated": "2015-09-20",
  "dateModified": "2015-09-20",
  "description": "We love to do stuff to help people and stuff",
  "articleBody": "You can paste your entire post in here, and yes it can get really really long.",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Steve"
  },
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://example.com/article"
  }
}
```

In it, you see that the `@context` is set, so from that context you can more concisely reference a `@type` called `BlogPosting`. Then you get direct access to using the properties in JSON.

Oh I will note, I have never used JSON-LD, just knew about it for years. I spent the past hour looking through the [JSON-LD Spec](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld), and the [IRI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987), trying to figure out how to reference properties and values from other code, and generally how to organize JSON-LD.

**What does the hashtag `#` mean in detail in the JSON-LD?**

For example, they have this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "label": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"
  },
  "@id": "",
  "label": "Just a simple document"
}
```

When I visit the url http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema, I get some raw RDF text. I see `label` as a property definition in the RDF, but is the context label `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label` just giving us a "casual" / mental association between that RDF text and our JSON-LD code? To me it doesn't seem a computer could:

1. Fetch the content at `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema`.
2. Realize it is RDF.
3. Parse the RDF.
4. Dig into the `label` property.
5. And use that to know how to type the label property in our JSON-LD.

Another example is [here](https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/blob/main/examples/syntax/example-003-Context-for-the-sample-document-in-the-previous-section.json), using `http://schema.org`:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",   
    "image": {
      "@id": "http://schema.org/image",   
      "@type": "@id"   
    },
    "homepage": {
      "@id": "http://schema.org/url",   
      "@type": "@id"   
    }
  }
}
```

When I visit http://schema.org/url, it is an HTML page (not RDF or JSON), and it shows like this.

[image]

---

They don't appear to have a `http://schema.org/url.json` or `.rdf` URL, so again it appears this "mental association" between `http://schema.org/url` and an actual URL property isn't something that is processed or figured out by a computer, but is simply a rough mental association. Basically, we added the `http://schema.org/url` HTML webpage so if you happen to visit `http://schema.org/url` it shows something, and because it's nice to have some web docs :). But there's not a technical need to have a website or JSON to download for definitions or whatnot. In the end, the links like `http://schema.org/url` are simply strings which are used as identifiers. Am I correct in that?

Then that would mean the `#` hashtag like `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label` or others, is simply another string, but the code which compiles JSON-LD splits off the after-hashtag part and uses it to lookup and type properties in the JSON. It doesn't, however, have any real meaning as being hosted on a webpage under that domain/URL.

So say I have a bunch of URLs I want to create:

- `/person/john-kennedy`
- `/atom/hydrogen`
- etc.

Each which has a bunch of possibly deeply-nested properties/objects/values. So could I just do:

```
{
  "@context": "https://mywebsite.org",
  "@type": "atom",
  "slug": "hydrogen",
  "name": "Hydrogen",
  "bindsTo": [{ "@id": "https://mywebsite.org/atom/oxygen" }]
}
```

Or even better, somehow do something like this:

```
{
  "@context": "https://mywebsite.org",
  "@type": "atom",
  "@id": "/atom/hydrogen",
  "name": "Hydrogen",
  "bindsTo": [{ "@id": "/atom/oxygen" }]
}
```

In short, **what am I allowed to do to link data using JSON-LD in as clean a way as possible (minimal amount of text)?**

- Does there need to be an actual web-presence backing the actual structured JSON data, or is it just out of convention or to create a somewhat friendly user experience, but not required for the machine?
- Is the hashtag just a convention for reaching into properties? Can the hashtag be used to deeply dig into properties (or array items), like `#foo/bar[1]/baz` which would dig into `{ foo: { bar: [ { baz: 1 }, { baz: 2 } ] } }` to return 2? Or is the hashtag actually used by the hosting website somehow?

Comment: read more https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#the-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to provide the RDF definition of the vocabulary/term when resolving the term URI, but it’s not required. Not least because any kind of URI can be used for RDF terms, not only resolvable URIs (e.g., [`urn`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name) or [`tag`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_URI_scheme) instead of `http`).

There are several ways to provide the vocabulary definition in a machine-readable way. The W3C Working Group Note [*Best Practice Recipes for Publishing RDF Vocabularies*](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-vocab-pub/) documents some of them.

[Appendix B](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-vocab-pub/#naming) explains the role of `#` (vs. `/`) in RDF term URIs. It’s just a way to build the URI namespace for the vocabulary (and can also be used to distinguish between the term/thing and the document where the term/thing is described).

And yes, the essential role of RDF term URIs is that they serve as globally unique identifiers.

---

JSON-LD is special, compared to the other RDF syntaxes, that remote JSON-LD contexts can be loaded. For example in the case of Schema.org, their JSON-LD context is linked in a Link HTTP header when accessing the front page (using the [`alternate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#alternate-document-location) link type). Such a context merely allows to write shorter JSON-LD.

This and other JSON-LD features might be confusing when learning about the Linked Data background. It might be helpful to "think" about the data in [triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_triple) form. The popular RDF syntax [Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) is close to this concept. If you know how the triples should look like, it’s just a matter of using JSON-LD’s syntax features to materialize what you want to say. In many cases it’s easier to write/generate Turtle and then to convert it into JSON-LD (or any other RDF syntax) automatically.

The JSON-LD

```
# on https://mywebsite.example.com/
{
  "@context": "https://vocabulary.example.org",
  "@type": "Atom",
  "@id": "/atom/hydrogen",
  "name": "Hydrogen",
  "bindsTo": [{ "@id": "/atom/oxygen" }]
}
```

could be expressed in Turtle like this:

```
@prefix : <https://vocabulary.example.org/> .

<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen>
  a        :Atom ;
  :bindsTo <https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/oxygen> ;
  :name    "Hydrogen" .
```

```
@prefix : <https://vocabulary.example.org/> .

<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> a        :Atom .
<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> :bindsTo <https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/oxygen> .
<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> :name    "Hydrogen" .
```

```
<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> a                                        <https://vocabulary.example.org/Atom> .
<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> <https://vocabulary.example.org/bindsTo> <https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/oxygen> .
<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> <https://vocabulary.example.org/name>    "Hydrogen" .
```

```
<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <https://vocabulary.example.org/Atom> .
<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> <https://vocabulary.example.org/bindsTo>          <https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/oxygen> .
<https://mywebsite.example.com/atom/hydrogen> <https://vocabulary.example.org/name>             "Hydrogen" .
```